# Not receiving subscription url in the list of headers provided by SNS in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, restify

So, I'm using restifyJS to receive SNS notifications and I have created a topic for the same and have subscribed to it using the appropriate ARN. I have used a https end point in which when I request for a confirmation, I'm getting the following headers when I request for a confirmation.

```js
{ 
  connection: 'upgrade',
  'x-real-ip': '*****************My IP address *****************',
  'x-forwarded-for': '*************My IP address ************',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'content-length': '1530',
  'x-amz-sns-message-type': 'SubscriptionConfirmation',
  'x-amz-sns-message-id': '*************************************',
  'x-amz-sns-topic-arn': 'arn:aws:sns:ap-south - ************',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
  'user-agent': 'Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate' 
  }
```

But I'm not getting the subscription URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the url is in the request body. Also notice that the body is JSON but the content-type is set to text/plain which may cause some parsers to provide an empty request body. 
You can provide restify with a text/plain formatter that parses the json content for SNS messages, according to the existence of the 'x-amz-sns-message-type' header.

Comment: You can now have Amazon SNS set the right `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. To achieve that, modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

Answer (score 1):

It isn't in the headers... it's in the request body (the "JSON document").

> Based on the type specified by the header field `x-amz-sns-message-type`, your code should read the JSON document contained in the body of the HTTP request and process the message.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html